# Quadratic Residue modulo $nm$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime and $b \in (\mathbb Z/ mn \mathbb Z)^\times$.  Then $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $mn$ if and only if $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $m$ and modulo $n$.

I am struggling with this proof.  It seems like I should be able to do it but every time I get stuck.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Yes, but can i use it both directions or just the backwards direction?

Answer (score 3):

For the somewhat harder direction, suppose that $s^2\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $t^2\equiv b\pmod{n}$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem the system of congruences $x\equiv s\pmod{m}$ and $x\equiv t\pmod{n}$ has a solution.

If $x$ is a solution, then $x^2\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $x^2\equiv b\pmod{n}$. It follows that $x^2\equiv b\pmod{mn}$, and therefore $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $mn$.

We leave the other direction to you.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was doing, but was stuck on the fact that s and t have to be relatively prime, is that true?

Comment: No, they do not have to be relatively prime. The **moduli** $m$ and $n$ have to be relatively prime for the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but we are told that they are.