# Solvability of $a \equiv x^2 \mod b$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose you want to prove that $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a \equiv x^2 \mod b$. Write $b = \prod_{i = 1}^{k} p_i^{e_i}$, the prime factorisation of $b$.

Why is the equivalent with finding solutions to $a \equiv x_i^2 \mod p_i$? How does one apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See for example [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1020846/11619) and André's answer for reduction to all the moduli $p_i^{e_i}$ (using Chinese Remainder Theorem). Otherwise it does not always work. For example $x^2\equiv 3\pmod3$ is solvable byt $x^2\equiv 9\pmod 3$ is not. If $a$ is coprime to all the primes $p_i$ then you need to combine CRT and Hensel lifting.

Comment: I thought I had worked a general modular square root here once, but may be that thread got deleted (the question was IIRC bad, so that's not a loss). The best example where I used both lifting and CRT is [this calculation](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/162334/11619) finding square roots of $-1$ modulo $2873$.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1304739/11619) is the correct version for the statement when $b$ is odd. If $2$ is one of the prime factors, then you first need to cancel as many fours as you can, and then recall that all odd squares are $\equiv1\pmod8$. [A numerical example](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/401160/11619) of lifting square roots module a power of two.

Comment: So a proper proof of this should use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, Hensel's lemma and the additional assumption that $b$ is not divisible by a prime squared?

Comment: It is ok for $b$ to be divisible by a square of a prime. Hensel takes care of that part. What will cause a problem is when $\gcd(b,a)$ is not a square, but non-solvability will then be easy to deduce.

Comment: The route is (assuming $\gcd(a,b)=1$): 1) Find the square roots modulo $p_i$ by whatever means you can (they may not exist, in which case you can conclude that there are no solutions). Do this for all $i$. 2) Whenever $p_i\neq2$, Hensel lifting then gives you the solutions modulo $p_i^{e_i}$. If $p_i=2$, then you need to first check solvability modulo $8$, and use Hensel from that point onwards. 3) The solutions modulo $p_i^{e_i}$ for all $i$ can then be combined to find the solutions modulo $b$.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this more carefully tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the ring $\mathbf Z/b\mathbf Z$ is isomorphic to the product of rings $\displaystyle\prod_i\mathbf Z/p_i^{e_i}\mathbf Z$.

Thus a number is a square modulo $b$ if and only if its images in each of the factors is a square.

Furthermore, *Bézout's identity* is  the tool to go back  from the set of squares modulo each of $p_i^{e_i}$ to square modulo $b$.

Some details on the workflow:

- Suppose $x_i$ is a square modulo $p_i^{e_i}$,  $x_j$
  a square modulo $p_j^{e_j}$. We have to find an $x$ such that 
  $$\begin{cases}x\equiv x_i\mod p_i^{e_i}\\x\equiv x_j\mod p_j^{e_j}\end{cases}$$
  Let $\;u\mkern1mu p_i^{e_i}+v\mkern1mu p_j^{e_j}=1$ a Bézout relation between $p_i^{e_i}$ and $p_j^{e_j}$. Clearly  $\;u\mkern1mu  p_i^{e_i}\equiv 1\mod p_j^{e_j}$ and $\;v\mkern1mu p_j^{e_j}\equiv 1\mod p_i^{e_i}$. Hence a solution is:$$u\mkern1mu p_i^{e_i}x_j+v\mkern1mu p_j^{e_j}x_i\bmod p_i^{e_i}\mkern1mu p_j^{e_j}.$$
- Next step: solve the system of congruences:
  $$\begin{cases}y\equiv x\mod p_i^{e_i}\mkern1mu p_j^{e_j}\\ y\equiv x_k\mod p_k^{e_k}\end{cases}$$
- &c.

Comment: Doesn't that give you problems when $b$ is divisble by the square of a prime?

Comment: Indeed, he wrote $p^{e_i}$..

Comment: No special difficulty. Going back is straightforward when there two prime powers, and yo go nack probressively when the are more than two prime powers. The harder problem can be to find square roots modulo $p_i^{e_i}$.

Comment: And how would you do that? I can't see why it's not a problem..

Comment: @Riley: I gave some details. Please see my updated answer. Is that clear?

Comment: @Bernard, it certainly is. You, kind sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! Thanks!